# Image as smaller bits of image

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an image . I want the image to be split into 100 pieces (outside the user will have appearance of 100 small images as a single large image) , and upon clicking each smaller image (ie any  one of 100) , each image should be highlighted and shown as a separate image .

What is the best technique to do this ???

Comment: What have you tried? is this supposed to be with javascript or c#? Read [ask]

Comment: It sounds like `canvas` is the most suitable thing here.

Comment: Lazy as I am, I'd skip creating the small images and instead just have a map targeting the desired zoom image ... but this may not cover all your requirements of *highlighted and shown as a separate image*.

Comment: There's even the `<asp:ImageMap>`control if you need to create your map server-side.

Answer (score 0):

If that is ASP.Net app, then best idea would be to provide the image to web client and in javascript get info about [x,y] position of the mouse cursor on image, from there, computing rectangle, based on the way you want to split the image into sub-images and returning back the sub image , that contains given [x,y] position of the mouse cursor and displaying it.

Should be possible to do all in javascript, moving 100+1 images between client and server could be slow or getting the correct one as the mouse is moving, computation on the server, does not seem to be a good idea either.

Comment: There's no need for tracking the cursor position if you just use the [map html tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).